# Applying the Berry-Esseen theorem to non-identically distributed summands

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, central-limit-theorem, large-deviation-theory

I want to lower bound

\begin{align}
 \mathbb{P} \left( -\epsilon \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq 0 \right) &= \mathbb{P} \left( - \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2}} \leq  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2} \leq 0 \right) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)
\end{align}
where $\{X_i\}$ are mean zero, independent random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \sigma_i^2 \leq H^2$ and $\mathbb{E}[|X_i|^3] = \lambda_i^3 \leq H^3$.

From Equation $3$ in [Berry Esseen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem#Non-identically_distributed_summands), I have that

\begin{align}
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \leq C_0 \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 \right)^{-3/2} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^3
\end{align}
Loosening the bound above gives
\begin{align}
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \leq \frac{C_0}{\sqrt{n}} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)
\end{align}
Now I can write $(1)$ as

\begin{align}
F_n(0) - F_n \left(-  \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2}} \right)
\end{align}
which by $(2)$ can be lower bounded as

\begin{align}
\Phi(0) - \frac{2C_0}{\sqrt{n}} - \Phi\left ( -  \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2}} \right ) &\geq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2C_0}{\sqrt{n}} - \Phi\left ( -  \frac{\epsilon}{H \sqrt{n}} \right )
\end{align}
Can the last expression be improved to something like $K/\sqrt{n}$ for some constant $K$ for large $n$? I feel like I need some approximations to normal CDF $\Phi(x)$ for small $x$.

Comment: Expanding about $x=0$ gives $1/2 - \Phi(-x) = x/\sqrt{2\pi} - x^3/(6 \sqrt{2\pi}) + O(x^5)$. So it looks like you want $1/\sqrt{2\pi} > 2C_0$, though this appears to be false. You may not be able to "loosen" quite as much as you did.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me.